# Run script using a certain version of Abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

I want to run a python script without Abaqus GUI and this already works well with the command:

`abaqus cae nogui = scriptname.py`

As I want to include a subroutine I have to run it in `Abaqus version 12-1` but I have also `version 13-1` installed (running the script in cae, I always got an error while using 13-1 but not with 12-1).
With the command above I don't know which version will be used. Is there a way to specify the used version in the cmd?

Answer (score 1):

on windows using `abaqus cae` will call the most recent version of abaqus installed. If you want to run on a specific version use this call instead `abq6121 cae nogui = scriptname.py`